# Angular Highcharts Radial Bar Chart not working as expected

Tags: angular, highcharts

Hello I have an application which uses highcharts in one item I want to show one graph but it is not woking what i expected . My demo is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular7-playground-xyep74?file=src/app/app.component.ts) I want radial bar chart which is [link](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/polar-radial-bar)
but is gives normal polar chart. this is my chart options

```
 chartOptions = {
    chart: {
      type: "column",
      inverted: true,
      polar: true,
      backgroundColor: null,
      plotShadow: false,
      plotBorderWidth: null,
      plotBackgroundColor: null
    },
    pane: { size: "85%", innerSize: "20%", endAngle: 270 },
    xAxis: { categories: ["Coorparate", "Plant1", "Plant2"] },
    title: "",
    plotOptions: {
      column: {
        stacking: "normal",
        borderWidth: 0,
        pointPadding: 0,
        groupPadding: 0.15
      }
    },
    series: [
      {
        name: "ISCI",
        type: "column",
        data: [
          { y: 7, name: "", info: "" },
          { y: 28, name: "", info: "" },
          { y: 14, name: "", info: "" }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "ISVEREN",
        type: "column",
        data: [
          { y: 0, name: "", info: "" },
          { y: 0, name: "", info: "" },
          { y: 0, name: "", info: "" }
        ]
      }
    ]
  };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You used Highcharts v7.1.1 and the radial bar chart was added in v8.0.0. Updating Highcharts version fixes the problem.

---

**Live demo:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular7-playground-nvw5jr?file=src/app/app.component.ts

**Changelog:** https://www.highcharts.com/blog/changelog/#highcharts-v8.0.0